# React.js Page is empty after start express server + nodemon + webpack 1

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I have following setting and component

**webpack.config.js**

```
{
  "name": "reddice",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "server": "nodemon --watch server --exec babel-node -- server/index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.10.2"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
import path from 'path';

export default {
  devtools: 'eval-source-map',
  entry: path.join(__dirname, '/client/index.js'),
  output: {
    path: '/'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'client'),
        loaders: ['babel']
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js']

  }    
}
```

**client/index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App';

render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

**client/components/App.js**

import React from 'react';

```
export default () => {
  return (
    <h1>Hello from App component</h1>
  );    
}
```

**server/index.html**

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">

  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>

    <script source="bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

i run server with command npm run sever. Display *webpack: Compiled successfully*. But nothing happen. Empty page without errors in console web tools

Answer (score 0):

Your index.html assumes that your final bundle file is called 'bundle.js'. Webpack, by default, uses the name of the file you gave to your entry point.

Inside your configuration, output object, you have to specify the filename

```
module.exports = {
   // ..
   output: {
     //..
     filename: '/client/bundle.js'
   }
}
```

Remember to save the file inside the same folder where you have your index.html file